# Cannot Convert to ClassFactory

Tags: apache-flex, flash, datagrid, itemrenderer

I have this item renderer MyRenderer.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:HBox xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" implements="mx.core.IDataRenderer" >
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
        [Bindable]
            public var greylist : XML;

            public function newInstance() : * {
                return new MyRenderer();
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:HBox>
```

and try to append the item renderer to my datagridcolumn by a classfactory

```
myRenderer = ClassFactory(MyRenderer);
myRenderer.properties = { greylist: this.greylist };
```

Now when debugging I get the error that MyRenderer cannot be converted into classfactory.

Can someone please help me?

Thanks in advance

Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
myRenderer = new ClassFactory(MyRenderer);
```